# I am getting this.parent.acquire error in mssql Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database

I am getting (this.parent.acquire is not a function) error in the following code

```
   app.post("/add", (req,res) => {
   

  const config = {
      
    server: 'server',  //update me
    user: 'user', //update me
    password: 'pass',  //update me
    database: 'db',
    trustServerCertificate: true
   }
  
  let pool2 =  sql.connect(config)
  try {
    const transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool2)
    transaction.begin(err => {
           if(err) {
             console.log(err);
           }

        const request = new sql.Request(transaction)
        request.query('insert into fsraSample (A93) values (12345)', (err, result) => {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
          }

    
            transaction.commit(err => {
              if(err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
   
    
                console.log("Transaction committed.")
            })
        })
    })
  } catch(err) {
console.log();
  }
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});
```

Whats the issue here? I am using the above code to insert some data in sql server using node js

Comment: Did you mean to use `'insert into fsraSample (someColumnName) values (12345)'` instead?

Comment: Also, did you mean `await pool2` before trying to get a transaction?